# $_SESSION['myvar'] unsets upon reloading page

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables

I have a login form that submits to a simple "checklogin" file that starts a session and redirects to the index page if the "username" and "password" matches. On the index page, I have a function that redirects back to the login form page if the session id no longer matches.

I did an `echo $_SESSION['sid'];` on the index page and the session_id seems to have carried over just fine. However, when I reload the page, `$_SESSION['sid']` is unset and is no longer assigned a value. It proceeds to redirect back to the login page.

Below is my code. Any assistance appreciated.

FILE 1 - checklogin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$uid = username;
$pw = password;
if (($uid == 'username'   and $pw == 'password'))   
    {   
        $_SESSION['sid']=session_id();
        header("location:index.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

FILE 2 - index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['sid'] !== session_id()) {
header("location:login.php");
}
?>
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:
The servers are running PHP 5.4. It works fine, however, when I run it on localhost via XAMPP (PHP 7). Is there a workaround?

Comment: do you have session destroy on your index page ? remove that.

Comment: Nope. I don't have session_destroy(); anywhere on my site. @shazyriver

Comment: every time you refresh the session id is changed because you have session start on your page at the start. Base you check on some other variable

Comment: @shazyriver Right. However, I have also tried giving it a set value which doesn't work as well.

Comment: check my answer.